# Android handling state of ProgressBar onPause/onResume

Tags: android

Hi have a progressBar that i run. but when the user exits the app via the home button and then re-enters it by holding down the home button and selected the app. The progressBar setProgress flickers between an old value and a new one almost as if its remembering the previous state. I have created a function in my on pause/onResume methods to pause the timer save the values and on resume get those values and start the timer and progress bar again. The confusing thing is it works the onPause stuff works perfectly if the onPause function is run and the user stays in the app for example presses the back button. Does anyone know where im going wrong or how to correctly implement a progressBar using a CountDownTimer?

heres my code

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("Game","ONRESUME");

        loadData();
        layoutChecks();     
        loadViews();
        try {
            if(!myData.get("completed").equals("3")){
                hintCheck();
                getHints();
                startTimer();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.v("Game","ONPAUSE");
        try {
            if(!myData.get("completed").equals("3")){

                pauseTimer();
                updateData();

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onPause();

    } 



public void loadViews(){
  progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
                progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progressD = progressBar.getProgressDrawable();
}


public void prepareProgressBar(){
        progressD.setLevel(0);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressD.setLevel(points*100);
        progressBar.setProgress(points);
    }

    public void startTimer(){
        try {
         points = Integer.valueOf(myData.getJSONObject("Data").getString("points"));
         int timer = points;
         hasTimerCancelled = false;
         prepareProgressBar();
         counter = new MyCount(timer/2 * 1000,1000);
         counter.start(); 

        } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void pauseTimer(){

        try {
            counter.cancel();
            hasTimerCancelled = true;
            JSONObject Data = myData.getJSONObject("Data");
            Data.put("points", String.valueOf(points));
            myData.put("Data", Data);
            updateData();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{

        public long totaltime; 

        public MyCount(long totalTime, long countDownInterval) {
            super(totalTime, countDownInterval);
        totaltime = totalTime;

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        counter.cancel();
        points = 0;
        progressBar.setProgress(0); 



        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


            if(!hasTimerCancelled){
                if(points > 0){

                 points = points - 1;

                }

                progressBar.setProgress((int) totaltime);   

            }

        }

    }
```